# Apache / PHP / .htaccess routing filename to filename.php

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to debug a php site and I've got a routing problem that I can't figure out.

It's a custom built site and most of the requests are routed via index.php

The problem I am having is that on the live server (Linux / Apache): 
`http://www.sitename.com/cart` is routed through index.php as it should be.

but on my test server (osx / apache):
`http://www.sitename.com/cart` goes straight to `http://www.sitename.com/cart.php` without being routed through index.php

I assume it's something to do with the .htaccess file (below) but I can't figure out what. Also the .htaccess file is the same on both servers so I don't understand why it's working differently, any help much appreciated.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_ssl.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.s?html$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.s?htm$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.s?xml$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.s?asp$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.s?aspx$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [PT]



#php_flag display_errors off
php_value default_charset ISO-8859-1
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc on
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
```

The virtual host file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jim/Sites/sitename.com/public_html"
    ServerName sitename.com
    ServerAlias www.sitename.com
        <directory "/Users/jim/Sites/sitename.com/public_html/">
           Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
        </directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you install the rewrite Engine?

Comment: it's working fine on other sites, could it be something to do with vhosts- i've edited the question to include the file

Comment: The virtual host is this almost the same as on the server. Because I still think there is something wrong with the rewrite on your own computer.

Comment: Thanks, Perry, you're right it was something on my computer, the multiviews in the virtual host, see answer by Jon Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of this line in your vhost config:

```
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
```

Not sure why you need `Multiviews` to be set to "on" but it's part of [mod_negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) and processes the request *before* mod_rewrite does. It takes requests like `/cart` and decides whether there's a fuzzy match against an existing resource. It sees `/cart.php` and assumes that's what you want and serves up the request before mod_rewrite even gets a chance to do anything. You can turn it off by adding a `-` in front:

```
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI -MultiViews
```

You can also do this via the htaccess file's `Options` directive:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```